# Shall I use PHP's unset function every time I am done working with variables?

Tags: php

My question is really simple, I fetch data from database and store them as variable for future use. After done working with the variables, is it cost-efficient to use the unset function of PHP to free up the memory? What I mean by 'cost-efficient' is whether is it worth calling the function multiple times in hope of clearing the memory to reduce up page load time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How important is it to unset variables in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617672/how-important-is-it-to-unset-variables-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php#86347)

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null)

"unset() does just what it's name says - unset a variable. It does not force immediate memory freeing. PHP's garbage collector will do it when it see fits - by intention as soon, as those CPU cycles aren't needed anyway, or as late as before the script would run out of memory, whatever occurs first.

If you are doing $whatever = null; then you are rewriting variable's data. You might get memory freed / shrunk faster, but it may steal CPU cycles from the code that truly needs them sooner, resulting in a longer overall execution time."

Comment: You might want to add that you are quoting a user comment, not the php documentation itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use unset when you are dealing with huge data like if you are dealing with arrays.

Comment: Maybe this link is helpful for you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298206/php-when-to-use-unset

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need to call the function multiple times unless you use the same variable name for different values - which I do not recommend.

unset($variable1, $variable2, $variable3)

I use unset at the end of my loops and to unset my arrays at the end of my code.

I do not really need to use unset unless I really have to - loops again here for a known php weirdness - or I have really huge arrays.