# Assigning NULL to a variable in PHP: what does that do?

Tags: php, null

In maintaining code, I'm encountering loops, where at the end of the loop several variables are set to `NULL` like so: `$var = NULL;`. From what I understand in the manual, NULL is meant mostly as something to compare against in PHP code. Since `NULL` has no type and is not a string or number, outputting it makes no sense.

I unfortunately cannot provide an example, but I think the NULL values are being written to a file in our code. My question is: does `$var` have a value after the assignment, and will echoing/writing it produce output?

**EDIT:** *I have read the PHP manual entry on* `NULL`. There is no need to post this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php in a comment or answer, or top downvote me for not having RTM. Thank you!

Comment: I mentioned in my post, before I edited it, that the manual does not answer my question. I sort of meant to imply that I'd actually read it. I assume you're one of the downvoters? Thanks a lot man.

Comment: You might want to add some actual (relevant) code showing how `NULL` is used. Otherwise you'll only get RTM-like answers, as your questions seem to point out that you do not understand the use of `NULL` (in PHP)

Comment: I down-voted your question, because it is vague, it contains unnecessary details about your job and lacks relevant details on the use case. This results in the variety of (supposedly) non-helping answers. My down-vote is not because to did or did not read the manual (although that was also not very clear before your edit)

Comment: How is it now? (apart from the lack of use cases, of course)

Comment: Also, thanks for explaining the downvote! I don't mind downvotes but I'd like to learn from them :)

Comment: I guess that _"will echoing/writing it produce output?"_ is your actual question :) You can test this yourself very easily with a small PHP application, but hopefully someone is able to give you a proper answer! (I'll 'un-down-vote' your question due to its current state)

Comment: You're absolutely right. I don't have very much time at the moment and feel sort of bad for leaving this question alone for days... Salman A's answer is very helpful, I upvoted his and another answer. As soon as I can manage it, I'll write a small app and if that helps me out, I'll post an answer myself.

Answer (score 3):

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ php -r '$i="foo"; print "ONE\n"; var_dump($i); unset($i); print "TWO\n"; var_dump($i); $i=NULL; print "THREE\n"; var_dump($i); print "\n"; if (isset($i)) print "Set.\n"; if (is_null($i)) print "is_null\n";'
ONE
string(3) "foo"
TWO
NULL
THREE
NULL
is_null
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

The result of `isset()` will be boolean false, but the variable is still defined.  The `isset()` function would be better named `isnotnull()`.  :-P

Note that `is_null()` will also return true for a value that has never been set.

Yay PHP.

Answer (score 2):

`null` is pretty much just like any other value in PHP (actually, it's also a different data type than string, int, etc.).

However, there is one important difference: `isset($var)` checks for the var to exist and have a non-null value.

If you plan to read the variable ever again before assigning a new value, `unset()` is the wrong way to do but assigning `null` is perfectly fine:

```
php > $a = null;
php > if($a) echo 'x';
php > unset($a);
php > if($a) echo 'x';
Notice: Undefined variable: a in php shell code on line 1
php >
```

As you can see, `unset()` actually deletes the variable, just like it never existed, while assigning `null` sets it to a specific value (and creates the variable if necessary).

A useful use-case of `null` is in default arguments when you want to know if it was provided or not and empty strings, zero, etc. are valid, too:

```
function foo($bar = null) {
    if($bar === null) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Null in PHP means a variable were no value was assigned.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

Comment: I'm afraid that was not my question. I made sure to RTFM before posting... :)

Comment: It is usually a good idea to link to the english version of a manual instead of its $other_language version.

Comment: @toon81 well the manual does seem to answer your question(s) as it states the uses of null and even shows that `$var = NULL` is perfectly legal

Comment: Who says that that isn't legal? Read the title of the question. How does that manual page answer my question?

Comment: sorry that it didn't answer your question correctly ! I understand now what you meant :-). Happy to see that ghoti answered your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A variable could be set to `NULL` to indicate that it does not contain a value. It makes sense if at some later point in the code the variable is checked for being `NULL`.

A variable might be explicitly set to NULL to release memory used by it. This makes sense if the variable consumes lots of memory (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/584960/87015)).

Dry run the code and you might be able to figure out the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the purpose of the null implementation based off of the information provide is to clear the variable.

You can unset a variable in PHP by setting it to NULL or using the function [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

> unset() destroys the specified variables.
>
> The behavior of unset() inside of a function can vary depending on
>   what type of variable you are attempting to destroy.
>
> If a globalized variable is unset() inside of a function, only the
>   local variable is destroyed. The variable in the calling environment
>   will retain the same value as before unset() was called.

Answer (score -1):

Null is a special data type which can have only one value, which is itself. Which is to say null is not only a data type but also a keyword literal a variable of data type null is a variable that has no value assigned to it when a variable is created without a value it is automatically assigned a value of null this is so that whatever garbage was in that memory location before is cleared out otherwise the program may try to process it