# Differences between $var = null and unset($var)

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's better at freeing memory with PHP: unset() or $var = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null)

As far as the garbage collection goes, is 1 better than the other in any circumstances?

EDIT:
Particularly if `$var` is a very large variable with a lot of levels of recursion and other objects (so to do with recursive cleanup of large objects)

EDIT:
Removed this:
I can think of only 1 thing, and that's that `isset($var)` will respond differently in either case.

Because apparently I was mistaken... They both react the same.

Comment: Why do you need to unset it? What's wrong with automatic doing that as soon as variable is out of scope?

Comment: "is a very large variable with a lot of levels of recursion and other objects" -- so?

Comment: It's to do with weak references. The variable never actually goes "out of scope" per se, it just needs to be cleaned up when it becomes invalid.

Comment: There is no weak references in php, isn't there?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.weakref.php

Comment: It's a fantastic addition... Highly needed for high performance apps.

Comment: ok, it is extension. But back to the question: why do you need to unset the variable? Is there any issues with memory amount required by script? Is your script a "daemon"-like (the one that works continuously)?

Comment: No, but it provides a cache-like function. Basically, you load a whoooooole lot (millions) of objects, and you keep cache the most important using a weak reference... That way, if the variable is in scope somewhere, it keeps the reference in cache. If not, it's free to be collected. I need to delete the reference object when the contained var goes out of scope.

Comment: @FuzziBear: reference is removed by php when variable goes out of scope. "if the variable is in scope somewhere" --- there is only one thread in php, so there is no "somewhere"

Comment: "and you keep cache the most important using a weak reference" --- if you want your GC to work as normal - don't use weakref extension. As simple as 1-2-3 ;-)

Comment: Whilst there's only 1 thread, you can have a very complex object hierarchy. If you load image data and store it in a class somewhere, you really only want to cache it for as long as it's already in memory (anything else is a waste). Weak references are REALLY important for very large data in very large scale applications.

Comment: @Michael: whilst it's similar (and my use case could have been answered by that if I had have found it in my google search), I think there are more subtle differences like the reference and undefined notice behaviours that make this a question in and of itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unset` does not force immediate memory freeing but leaves it for the gc. `$var = null;` however *forces* immediate memory release.

**See example:**

```
 // $a = NULL; (better I think)
 $a = 5;
 $b = & $a;
 $a = NULL;
 print "b $b "; // b 
 print(! isset($b)); // 1 
 ?>
```

It is also worthy to note that in the ***case of an array*** unset ***`destroys`*** the variable completely. i.e.:

```
<?php
$ar = array(1,2,3,4);
var_dump($ar);
echo "<br />";

unset($ar[2]);
var_dump($ar);
echo "<br />";

$ar[1] = null;
var_dump($ar);
?>
```

***Returns the output:***

> ```
> array(4) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(4) } 
> array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [3]=> int(4) } 
> array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> NULL [3]=> int(4) }
> ```

Comment: I wish I could select multiple answers for the solution... Since I can only select 1, this is basically what I was looking for. For future readers, RiaD's and xdazz's answers also give very helpful information for other use cases. Xdazz really went the extra mile with explanation about GC internals ;)

Comment: How does that example demonstrate anything about "forcing" the garbage collector?!

Answer (score 4):

```
unset($var);
// You will get Undefined variable Notice.
if ($var) {}

$var = null;
// it's ok.
if ($var) {}
```

***Addition of GC of php.***

PHP's Garbage Collection is based on the `refcount` of the `zval`, if `refcount` becomes 0, then the `zval` can be freed.

So if `$a = $b = array(/*a very large array*/);`, unset only `$a` or only `$b` won't free the memory of the large array.

`unset($a);` or  `$a = null` or assign another value to `$a` will all let the `refcount` decrease by 1, but the memory will be freed only when the `refcount` decrease to 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = 5;
$b = &$a;
unset($b); //just say $b should not pointer to any var
print $a; // 5


$a = 5;
$b = &$a;
$b = null;
print $a; // nothing, because $a = null
```