# In Javascript what is more efficient, deleting an element or setting it to undefined explicitly

Tags: javascript

Say I have an Associative Array Foo, with key bar and value xyz.

```
 console.log(Foo['bar']);

 >> xyz

 delete Foo['bar'];
 console.log Foo['bar'];

 >> undefined

 Foo['bar'] = 'xyz';
 console.log(Foo['bar']);

 >> xyz

 Foo['bar'] = undefined;
 console.log (Foo['bar']);

 >> undefined
```

My question is, which of the two is more efficient, do they differ in any way? Is there a scenario when I should use one over the other?

Thanks!

Results:

Thank you to everyone for helping out and showing me jsperf. Setting it to undefined appears to be (relatively) significantly faster then delete, although all the caveats pointed out below are also very interesting (in fact, I will probably be using delete a lot going forward to avoid future errors out of leftfield).

Comment: hop over to http://www.jsperf.com and find out.

Comment: Already tested here? http://jsperf.com/delete-vs-undefined-vs-null/3

Comment: Setting a key to `undefined` doesn't get rid of the key in your object: http://i.imgur.com/LvPDC.png

Comment: Similar post in php tag; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667137/the-difference-between-unset-and-null/13667734#13667734

Comment: here a working benchmark: http://jsben.ch/#/gu1Gi

Comment: See https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/get-ready-a-new-v8-is-coming-node-js-performance-is-changing-46a63d6da4de about changes in this area in the new V8 version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll make a negative performance difference in the long term as `b` is still considered a property after the latter assignment to `undefined`. For example:

```
var a = { b : 0 };

a.b = undefined;

a.hasOwnProperty("b");
>>> true
```

Same goes for the `in` keyword (`"b" in a` is true) so this will most likely hinder iteration when part of a larger object.

Comment: If you use "delete a.b" you will see that a.hasOwnProperty('b') turns to false, so that's another option

Answer (score 9):

After some experimentation and research, I have concluded that, at least on my machine, using the `delete` operator is 6 times slower than assigning `undefined`. Despite that, it is important to remember what [jAndy said about the prototype chain and property existence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13982339/9821959).

If you'd like to re preform my tests, I instantiated an array of 50,000 items. (Item count doesn't matter as long as it is big enough to show a difference between both tests.)

```js
let arr = new Array(500000).fill(null).map(() => ({"item": 42}));
```

And then I timed the amount of time it took to assign each object's item property to undefined in the array against the amount of time it took to delete each object's item property in the array.

```js
console.time("Assignment To Undefined");
arr.forEach(object => object.item = undefined);
console.timeEnd("Assignment To Undefined");

//Reset the array here...

console.time("Deletion");
arr.forEach(object => delete object.item);
console.timeEnd("Deletion");
```

All of my results:

- Deletion: Approximately 200 - 170 ms.
- Assignment: Approximately 15 - 40 ms.

Answer (score 8):

Be aware that deleting a property from an object will replace that property with one of the same name if one exists on the prototype chain.

Setting the property to null or undefined will simply mask it.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't benchmark the performance of those operations (as I mentioned in a comment, just create a little benchmark on http://www.jsperf.com), but I'll lose some words on the difference.

You will always be good on `delete`ing properties, wheras setting them to `undefined` or `null` will let people and/or code hang, which check with the `IN` operator.

Like

```
if( 'bar' in Foo ) { }
```

will still return `true` if you set `Foo.bar` to `undefined`. It won't if you go with `delete Foo.bar`.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent response, I upvoted it. I gave it to David as his also mentioned hasOwnProperty.

Answer (score 5):

Apart for benchmarking the actual action of deleting or assigning to `undefined`, you should also consider the future performance implication of using the object after you changed it.

I can think of two:

1. Once the property is deleted, accessing it will cause JavaScript to look it up in [the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), whereas if the property still exists on the object (with `undefined` value), the prototype chain won't be searched.
2. Deleting the property changes the "object shape" and might hurt [JavaScript optimizations](http://richardartoul.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/04/26/hidden-classes.html).

Answer (score 4):

[From the link I commented](http://jsperf.com/delete-vs-undefined-vs-null/3):

> The delete operator removes a property entirely. Setting a property to
>   undefined removes the value. Setting a property to null changes the
>   value to the null value.
>
> Technically they are not equivalent, but in practice they are often
>   used to mean the same thing: that a property is unset.

Setting the object to `null` was the fastest.

Some good resources to understanding these operations:

- [Understanding delete](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#misconceptions)
- [Understanding JavaScript’s ‘undefined’](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/)

Comment: null is grossly misused in the js code I've seen. It signifies an intentional null value, as opposed to a value that has not been set. Good link to point out they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Since deleting the property doesn't do the same thing programmatically as setting it to undefined, it really depends upon what programming outcome you want.

`delete Foo['bar'];` removes the `bar` property from the `Foo` object.  It will not be there if someone iterates over the direct properties of `Foo`.

`Foo['bar'] = undefined` sets the property to undefined, but it still exists on the object and will still be there, but have a value of `undefined`.

So, if you want to get rid of the property, use `delete`.  If you want the property to still be there, but have an `undefined` value, then set it to `undefined`.

If you really just want to know which is fastest and for some reason don't care out the programming difference, then go to jsperf.com, make yourself two comparison test cases and run the jsperf in a bunch of different browsers that are relevant to you.  All performance questions should be answered with relevant real world testing.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent response, I upvoted it. I gave it to David as his also gave code example cases.