# How to remove element from array object use in redux reduce state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

In my react app I create a store and reducer using redux.

And I have one state name as "cart" which is an object array.

And I want to remove and an element which I pass the id as a payload in **reducer** case only.

How can I remove an element from this state which is id equal to payload ID?

**This is cart state structure**

[image]

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
       case actionTypes.QUANTITY_COUNT:
            const newCart = {...state.cart};
            if (newCart[action.id].quantity === 1){
                 //here i want to remove element from cart/newCart of Id as action.id
              }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `cart.filter( (c) => c.id !== action.payload ),` this logic for delete

Comment: @Sheikh this is not working in my case because the cart is an array of object and it throws error when I use this. Don't know why

Comment: It's a normal method for delete, if you have faced an error, then you need to show your code.

Comment: @Sheikh yes sure, How can I show you my code?

Comment: Please edit your main post and explain more details about your error or problem

Comment: It's not working because cart is not an array of objects, but an object of objects based on your console.log

Comment: yes something like the same So what should I do now for removing it?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of the relevant code in your issue.

Comment: I would look into fixing on why that's not an array, since I believe that's what you were looking for first, right?

Comment: @buzatto yes, but the focus is to remove element from this.

Comment: Seems the `id` is also the object key, `delete newCart[action.id]`.

Comment: guys, I update my question with code where I want to remove element

Comment: @DrewReese ```delete newCart[action.id]``` Yess.......this works for me. Thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

Actually `delete` keyword is not designed for doing this task. Also, the idea behind the reducer is to make a new state so copying state and then deleting an element is something you must try to do in proxied packages such as [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) not js itself.

here are some tips for working with objects as there are many number of questions about state change with objects.

```js
const state = { isActive: true, props: { userId: {} } }
Object.keys(state) // ['isActive', 'props']
Object.entries(state) // [['isActive', true], ['props', { userId: {} }]]
Object.keys(state).map((key, index) => state[key]) // // [true, { userId: {} }]
```

as I mentioned deleting doesn't play a good role here instead the better way to change sub-part object is using immer, or filter

```js
const newCart = Object.keys(state.cart).filter(() => state.cart[action.id].quantity !== 1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the logic of `delete` not being designed for this task, it is literally its purpose to remove a key-value from an object. Also, `Object.keys(state.cart)` returns an array of *just* the object's keys. Sure, you can filter the key from the array, but now the `newCart` state is mutated to an array and the values weren't persisted to the next state.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, `delete` doest lots of prototypal things that are redundant here, it is [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44008788/10321531) and accessing a key in that object has [perf issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41236408/10321531)

Comment: I don't disagree these being valid points (good resources), but they are (a) rather old posts, in the JS/webdev timeline, and (b) each delete is a single atomic operation and not the most expensive operation for React. IMHO this falls fully in the premature-optimization bucket. I'll concede that instead of deleting the entry, setting the value to `undefined` is just as readable and potentially accomplishes the same result in a more performant manner.

Comment: I agree with you @DrewReese, setting undefined is a better solution, but we should be careful in mapping in presentational component e.g. filtering undefined value or handle it in a component (`return null`). From a personal understanding, I guess browser engines optimize and improve their speed on functions which is dominant in the web, such as string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this logic, this is works for my case:

```
      const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
       case actionTypes.QUANTITY_COUNT:
            const newCart = {...state.cart};
            if (newCart[action.id].quantity === 1){
                  delete newCart[action.id]
                 
              }
}
```

Comment: OP's cart is clearly an object, for some reason, not an array. This answer doesn't fit the question.