# Why does "isset($a[0]) and unset($a[0]);" cause syntax error?

Tags: php, unset

My Code:

```
$a = [];
isset($a[0]) and unset($a[0]);
```

it shows **`"syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET)"`**

but

```
$a = [];
isset($a[0]) and exit();
```

it **works!**

Both of `exit()` and `unset()` are returning no value. Why does one work but not the other?

Comment: could you shar your error info?

Comment: `exit` doesn't return a value because the program _exits_!

Comment: code is so ugly, what exactly you want to do?

Comment: @AmbalMani 'syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET)'

Comment: @Umair I want delete a value from an array

Comment: For Ex : `$val = 1;
$a[] = $val;
 print_r($a); 
isset($a[0]); unset($a[0]);
print_r($a); `      Could you able understood what kind of issue yopu made

Comment: You should read [this (*"How does PHP's unset work internally"*)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24557958/2518525)

Answer (score 3):

`unset` is a language construct, not a real function (this is why you get `T_UNSET` and not a more generic term), so it doesn't play by the same rules as a normal function would.  `isset` and `exit` are also language constructs, but they behave more like normal functions.

Answer (score 0):

As I asked in comments and you said you want to delete a value from Array,

Why not simply write

```
$a = [];
if(isset($a[0])){
unset($a[0]);
// And exit() if you want to
}
```

Comment: Because this is simple way to write and read ... else, future programmers working on your code will say bad words about you :P