# does unset() destroys PHP GD resources?

Tags: php, variables, gd

i use a `for` loop to unset all of the leftover variables in my script, to save some memory.
My question is, will `unset($variable);` delete `$variable` if it is a PHP gd resource, like the one created with `$variable = imagecreatefrompng('url');`?

Comment: [This question should clarify things for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null).

Comment: you should use imagedestroy funtion, check http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagedestroy.php

Comment: @kraysak I know i can do that but there's over 50 GD resources and i can't just go through each one of them, so i have a function that unsets all variables, some of those variables are PHP gd resources and i was wondering if unset could destroy those as well.