# PHP best way of unsetting a variable

Tags: php, variables, reset

```
$num = 1;    
$var = ''

if ($num == 1) {
  $var = 'ONE';
}

if (isset($var)) {
  echo $var;
}

// Result: ONE
```

In the above example, which is best practice when checking against `isset()`?

```
$var = '';
```

or

```
$var = null;
```

Comment: Setting it to `null` maybe?

Comment: @Script47 or not setting it at all...

Comment: It would probably help if you explained what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @jcuenod I assume he wants to keep `$var` in the scope of the rest of the code and wants to make it outside of the `if statement` but isn't sure how to define it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's better at freeing memory with PHP: unset() or $var = null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null)

Comment: @Deena this is clearly not about freeing memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `$var = '';` near the top, `isset` will return `true` every time. What you want, is to check if the `$var` is `empty`.

Change:

```
if (isset($var)) {
  echo $var;
}
```

to

```
if (!empty($var)) {
  echo $var;
}
```

Otherwise, simply remove the original `$var = '';` near the top and you can continue to use `isset`.

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends more broadly on what you're trying to do.
I'm not convinced unsetting a variable is your best bet here.

However, PHP does have an [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function:

```
unset($var);
```

To be clear, I agree that checking for emptiness is probably a better idea

Comment: Especially when using references `unset()` has to be used.