# PHP clearing memory for an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, memory-management

I have a class, which (among other things) contains a simple array of objects instanced from another class.  (This array is small - containing only 1 to perhaps 4 objects.)

In the __destruct method of the first class I want to clear the contents (free the memory) of this array of objects.  In order to do this, do I:

1. iterate through the array, setting each index = null, then finally setting the array = null?
2. simply set the array = null?

Comment: use `unset($array);`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null but either way, there's no reason to do this on the individual elements of the array. Just null/unset the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by @splash58 you can use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to delete a variable.

```php
unset($array); // can be used on multiple as well: unset($var1, $var2, ...);
```

Unset will simply destroy the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Re: rjdown link.  Thanks.  I had previously read that question/answers.

From that post I concluded (perhaps incorrectly) that there appeared to be 2 (possible?) differences between unset($var) and $var = null.

1. the speed at which the memory is actually released.  ($var = null appeared to be faster.)
2. the processing load of the method.  (unset($var) appeared to present less of a load.)

For reasons, I decided on speed of memory release, and thus went with the use of the null assignment.

However, the question remained - the array would be null, but would the objects previously contained by the array be non-null and thus have to wait around for GC?

Since a test was actually easy to do, I did it.

I created about 1,000 child records for a parent class.  Then I instanced a new parent class and loaded the 1,000 child objects into the array.

I used memory_get_usage() in a test file, and ran a number of trials where:

1. the parent class' __destruct method simply unset the array of child objects.
2. the parent class' __destruct method iterated through the array, setting each instance = null, then unset the array.

Data as follows:

- using parent __destruct unset array

Start memory - 620288

memory after parent instanced and child array loaded - 1316952

memory after parent set to null - 620864

mem diff = 576

- using parent __destruct iterate array = null

Start memory - 620952

memory after parent instanced and child array loaded - 1317616

memory after parent set to null - 621528

mem diff = 576

(I also put a microtime interval across parent object creation, child array load, parent object destruction.  Tests for each of the 2 __destruct methods were essentially equivalent at around 10 ms.)

From this I conclude - there really isn't much of a difference.  Unset or null, whatever floats your boat.

(Perhaps I should have simply run my own tests prior to bothering the forum with a question.)

Again, thanks.