# remove session variable on page refresh

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables, infinite-scroll

I have an array of ids called $ids.  I use infinite scrolling to display sets of those ids ($subset_ids) which I then put into a session variable. When I loop back through the request, I remove $subset_ids from $ids so as not to display any id twice.

When I refresh the page, how do I destroy or unset the session variable so I start with the full array of $ids again?

Comment: Just do `$_SESSION['mykey'] = '';`, show your code !

Comment: unset($_SESSION['mykey'])

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($_SESSION['mykey']);
```

This will remove / delete the variable so you can redefine it with out interference from it's previous content.

Ahmad's suggestion `$_SESSION['mykey'] = '';` would also work, but [from what I have read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null) it seems to be less efficient.