# PHP: memory-optimized concatenation?

Tags: php, memory-management

Consider this code:

```
$fullText = $beforeStore . $store . $afterStore;
```

If `$store` is big and one wants to optimize memory usage (`memory_get_peak_usage`), they will find that here they use thrice the memory needed to keep `$store` since `$store . $afterStore` is another value of that size (or bigger) as well as `$beforeStore . $store . $afterStore`. So to optimize, I used

```
$fullText = $beforeStore . $store;
unset($store);
$fullText = $fullText . $afterStore;
```

which gives only twice in terms of `memory_get_peak_usage` and the final state (`memory_get_usage`) is the same as the initial (I omit `unset`ing `$beforeStore` and `$afterStore` here).

Is there some smart way to concatenate in this optimized manner but without writing 1+n lines of code where n is the number of concatenated strings? (or 2n if we want to unset each of the concatenated lines)

Comment: Instead of concatenating strings you can create an array of referenes to the values and use that instead of `$fullText`. Do you actually need a single variable holding everything?

Comment: and BTW, `unset` doesn't remove the variable from memory, https://stackoverflow.com/a/584982/2595450

Comment: @Al.G. well, in this particular case yes, `$fullText` is put into a file afterwards

Comment: In that case you can do a continuous `fputs`/`fwrite` loop with all the values and you won't need them in a single variable.

Comment: @MehdiBounya thanks, I'll check if that helps to optimize further

Comment: @Al.G. you're right, that's an option, probably I'll use that, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use string interpolation instead of concatenation, so it doesn't need to create intermediate strings for the partial results.

```
$fullText = "{$beforeStore}{$store}{$afterStore}";
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for :)