# Should I unset() the resource variable after calling the function that destroys it?

Tags: php

Say that I am using the `stream` resource type to open a file:

`$file = fopen('1.txt', 'w+');`

If I want to destroy the resource, I would call `fclose()`:

`fclose($file);`

But I think that `fclose()` only destroys the resource and not the variable itself, I know this because when I do the following:

```
<?php
    $file = fopen('1.txt', 'w+');
    fclose($file);

    xdebug_debug_zval('file');
?>
```

I get the following result:

```
file:

(refcount=1, is_ref=0),resource(3, Unknown)
```

Which means that the variable still exist in memory.

So should I call `unset($file)` after calling `fclose($file)` to destroy the variable?

Comment: [php free variable memory](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+free+variable+memory&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS688US688&oq=php+free+variable+&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57.4750j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: You should see the answer for that question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null)

Answer (score 1):

> So should I call unset($file) after calling fclose($file) to destroy the variable?

In my opinion, no, you shouldn't `unset` after `fclose`.

Here's why:

- You don't save much memory and PHP does garbage collection anyways.
- You make your code more noisy which means **less readability** and **less maintainability** for little to no benefit.

Of course there are *some* cases where `unset` makes sense or is needed.

I found [a nice read](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/18/1/10) about unset() where you can learn more.

Comment: *"and PHP does garbage collection anyways"* But the variable `$file` still have a `refcount` of `1` after calling `fclose($file)`, so it wouldn't be garbage collected, or will it?

Comment: @user7681202 Since this variable is globally defined it will be garbage collected once the script has ended.