# Does the garbage collector can collect elements which belongs to a script that is under `sleep()` condition?

Tags: php, garbage-collection

Does the garbage collector can collect elements which belongs to a script that is under `sleep()` condition?

I know that the garbage collector free objects from memory if they aren't referenced (so they are considered to be no more in use).

If the answer is yes, I can free resources before the script continues, so with a higher execution time I can use less memory.

Is my reasoning true?

I'll try to be clearer:

- the script is running
- in the script I make 3 variables eligible for being garbage collection: `$var1 = $var2 = $var3 = null;` *or other form to make it properly, this isn't the point*
- in the script I invoke `sleep(100);`
- here is where my question applies: before the time of 100 seconds ends, does the garbage collector can run to free `$var1`, `$var2` and `$var3`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but `sleep()` just pauses execution and so the objects are still needed.

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear. I'll insert an example.

Comment: Your variables are still in use, they can't be collected.

Comment: @Dharman, when a variable is set to `null` becomes eligible for the garbage collector, isn't true?I tried also unset($var1, $var2, $var3);

Comment: Why would it? What would happen to the null value then? It still has a value.

Comment: o_O i'm little confused... how can I make a variable eligible for garbage collection? In Java works as it.

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null

Comment: @NigelRen I read the post. But why did you suggest to read it? Only for the `clear variable` purpose or related of my question? (see my edit)

Comment: The garbage collector is not timing based, so using sleep() makes no difference.

Comment: @NikiC so when exactly it runs? If it isn't timing base, I may thinks I can trigger it.

Comment: Assuming you are referring to the cycle collector: When the number of GC roots exceeds a threshold.

Comment: @NikiC Hmm..... so if I define for example 1kk new variables the GC may be triggered?

Comment: Locked due to edit abuse.

Answer (score 1):

I think the space of deleted variables is released immediately. Use [memory_get_usage()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) to determine your required memory. This is shown by the following small test:

```
<?php
    echo memory_get_usage(false)." start <br>";
    $var1 = range(0,10000);  //a big array
    echo memory_get_usage(false)." create var1 <br>";
    unset($var1);  
    echo memory_get_usage(false)." unset var1 <br>";
```

Output:

```
424120 start 
952560 create var1 
424120 unset var1
```

Comment: If a variable falls out of scope and is not used in any other place of the currently executed code anymore, then it is garbage collected automatically. You can force this early by using unset() to end variables scope early.
What can the garbage collector do, if you clean up self all?