# Update price, status stock, post status form CSV (more 20k products) in WOOCOMMERCE (Memory runs out on 3000 products)

Tags: php, csv, memory, woocommerce, fgetcsv

I use the construction for read csv file (about 25000 lines) in my method `update()` of my class

```
if(($handle = fopen($this->csv_url, 'r')) !== false) {

        $row = 0;

        while(($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false)
        {
            if ($row === 0) { $row++; continue; }

            // Doing update a few meta in current product
            // I detect product by sku

            unset($data);
            $row++;
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }
```

Memory runs out on 3000 products. (250MB setup in php.ini file)

Does anyone have any ideas? Sorry for my English.

Comment: First of all, you can try to use `$data = null` instead of unset for faster memory freeing (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null).
Also, what about setting higher `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` and `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT`?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have tried use NULL - it still does not work. Also, memory_limit currently set 256MB (it is max).

Comment: 256MB isn't max, I've set up for a special use case of a certain request to 4GB. (4096MB)

Answer (score 2):

I have long resolved this issue; here is what I found:

In each loop iteration (I did it every 20), I use this function [`wp_cache_flush()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cache_flush/).

As a result, I have 86 MB of used memory without accumulation:

[image: screenshot]